# Timing circuit with a motor

Tags: timer, 555

I am attempting to make the circuit that is attached. It is simply a 5 second delay timer using a 555.

I want to add a small project motor on the output pin in addition to the LED. I would like the button to activate the motor for 5 seconds.

I am having a lot of trouble with getting this to work. The only time I have been successful is when I connected this in series and removed the resistor, but then there is no time delay and the motor and LED are only on when I hold the button.

I am stuck and would appreciate any help you can give.

[image]

Comment: ALL IC circuits need a supply bypass capacitor. Yours has none. Use 2.2M instead of 10k for the timing resistor.

Comment: I assume your 555 doesn't have enough current to drive the dc motor, add a power stage between the output of the 555 and the DC Motor. (BJT, MOSFET, Relay, etc.)

Comment: I'm sorely missing a decoupling capacitor on the supply of the 555, which has to switch large currents

Comment: man these breadboard diagrams are *confusing*. Do you happen to have a proper schematic of what you're doing?